# Objection to chat heading

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, pronunciation

This is not a question, but I object to the spelling of the transliterated word "Hashavu'a" as in, "[Visit our Parashat Hashavu'a Chat, going on right now.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/jewish-life-and-learning)"

The correct pronunciation, if one is emphasizing the 'Ayin, is Hashavua'. As in רוח, the [פתח is pronounced before the final radical](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6002/5) (letter of the Shoresh).

Normally I wouldn't criticize someone else's transliteration scheme, but it does seem as though the transliterator was attempting to insert some phonetic symbology to represent the 'Ayin, or at the very least to represent a distinction between the final two vowels. Attempting to do the latter is also incorrect, as [the vowels ought to merge nearly seamlessly](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2438/5).

Just my two cents; I hope I haven't offended anybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK; you got me. I'll fix it in the various locations, except for the already-archived transcripts and the scheduled chat itself, to which a bunch of people are already scubscribed.

Comment: I made the ad, and just found out about this today.

Comment: (The new version of the ad to fit with the new design will have this typo fixed.)